# Fire and foget methods in JAVA, methods then u don't need to wait

Tags: java, asynchronous, methods

I have an custom thread that waits for UDP packages. After receiving i want this thread to continue running and just send the information to another method. I checked @Asynchronous notation, but that seems to work only in javaEE. Any suggestions?

Comment: *"I have an custom thread that waits for UDP packages"* - Here's your answer.  Have another thread that can process them.  I'd recommend taking a look at [Executors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/executors.html)

Comment: @MadProgrammer I hate it when people post the answer as a comment. Post that as an answer and I'll upvote it.

Comment: @tbodt It seems so "cheap" to answer such a basic question :P - Done just for you ;)

Answer (score 1):

*"I have an custom thread that waits for UDP packages"* - That's your answer, have another thread that can process them.

I'd recommend taking a look at [Executors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/executors.html).  This way you can have multiple threads processing the incoming packets without the need to manage it all yourself

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is using Queues.

The thread that waits for UDP packets places the packet it finds onto a BlockingQueue. Another thread continually polls that queue and processes whatever it finds.

for example:

```
public class UdpReceivingThread extends Thread {

    private final BlockingQueue<UdpPacket> queue;

    public UdpReceivingThread(BlockingQueue<UdpPacket> queue) {
        this.queue = queue;
    }


    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            UdpPacket packet = listenForPacket();
            queue.put(packet);
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
public class ProcessingThread extends Thread {

    private final BlockingQueue<UdpPacket> queue;

    public ProcessingThread(BlockingQueue<UdpPacket> queue) {
        this.queue = queue; // Same queue instance as in UdpReceivingThread instances!
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(true) {
            UdpPacket packet = queue.take();
            process(packet);
        }
    }
}
```

Note that this approach is certainly related to using an Executor - an Executor essentially uses a BlockingQueue to manage Runnables, which wrap the method calls to process the UDP packet. This is just another way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
private static final ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();  
InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName("hostname");
while(true){  
    DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length, address, 4445);
    threadPool.execute(new Runnable(){  
         public void run(){  
           processPacket(clientConnection);   // write a method to do the packet processing
       }
    );               
}
```